# Unsure which answer to accept - Most correct or Most inline with question

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I asked [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946881/what-techniques-require-mutable-texture-storage) "What techniques require mutable texture storage"

Now Nicol's answer is probably best practice and has helped me the most. However it does not **directly** answer the question.

ananthonline directly answered the question from his own experiences but it gives less insight and good practices.

In these kind of situations where is the 'accept' best placed?

Comment: That is completely up to you, to be honest. Accept the answer you think deserves it most.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question here.

Comment: you da baws. you choose whatever you want. i'm serious.

Comment: Select the one which you actually used

Comment: Really doesn't matter which one you accept. The decision is totally up to you. Everyone has different standards: which one you thought was most interesting, most helpful, most directly applicable to the question, the one you actually used, etc. Whatever you do, just remember to upvote *both* of them!

Comment: Thanks folks. Sorry this was a duplicate, I really need to search a bit harder!